# Why is the following Calculus Theorem True?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist and are continuous near $(a,b)$ for a function $f(x,y)$, then the function $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$.

Could someone explain a geometric meaning or give an intuitive explanation of why
this theorem holds true? I don't understand why these two conditions are
sufficient on their own for a differentiable function.

Comment: What do you mean by $f_x$ and $f_y$? If you mean the partial derivatives in the $x$ and $y$ directions, then I don't think this is true.

Comment: Yes, I mean the partial derivatives in the $x$ and $y$ directions. I read the theorem in "James Stewart Calculus, 8th Edition", page 971. I made a small mistake in the question: instead of exist and continuous _at_ $(a,b)$ it should be _near_ $(a,b)$

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: You didn't. ...in the comment: *exist and continuous near*... in the question: *differentiable at*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $f_x$ and $f_y$ to be exist and be continuous it means that there are no "pointy" corners near f(a,b). Corners like you would get from $f(x,y) = |x| + |y|$ at (0,0).  The hard part to visualize is could there be a corner at some other axis, like a diagonal.  Basically the theorem is saying an fold in the fabric of f(x,y) near (a,b) would cause a non-continuous partial differential in either $f_x$, $f_y$ or both.

Comment: I just revisited this and I have a question: How can there be pointy corners if $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist but are not continuous?

Comment: @OmarAlmonajed - The idea of "near (a,b)" is implying the existence of a neighborhood.  A neighborhood in all directions contained in a circle of some radius.  It can be arbitrarily small, but not infinitely small.  So the partial differentials being continuous at all these points near (a,b) means that you can have a tangent plane that is a good approximation for f near (a,b).